# Unable to rollback GAE Deployment Transaction

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to use the appcfg.sh in the GAE Java SDK to rollback a stuck (in progress) deployment. However the rollback is failing because I have an space character in the Folder name for the Project:

appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/bin/appcfg.sh rollback "workspace/**Crowded\ Intelligence**/war/" (fails)
appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/bin/appcfg.sh rollback 'workspace/**Crowded\ Intelligence**/war/' (fails)
appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/bin/appcfg.sh rollback workspace/**Crowded\ Intelligence**/war/ (fails)

Any thoughts on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want to rename or renaming is not a solution for you, then you may do this:

cd /users/username/workspace/Crowded Intelligence/

now when in your project do

/users/username/downloads/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/bin/appcfg.sh rollback war

This way you dont mention the part with the space in it

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I had to rename the project folder to remove the space character, and then perform the rollback.......